# error running program in virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox, android, emulator

I tried installing an android emulator in my virtual box but I got the error message - "The version of opengl is too low, suggest upgrading the graphics driver." I would like to know if any has an idea on how I can resolve this problem. Hope to get some response.

Comment: Upgrade the graphics driver?

Comment: haha yes it seems obvious but this is a virtual box. How can I upgrade the graphics driver in a virtual box?